# google-cloud-bigquery pgk_resources

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sdk

I follow this Google guide: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python
And after run script I got an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pyc6eh4uk/PycharmProjects/fintech_python/bq_jobs/big_query_test.py", line 2, in <module>
        from google.cloud import bigquery
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
        __version__ = get_distribution('google-cloud-bigquery').version
      File "/home/pyc6eh4uk/Programms/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 311, in get_distribution
        if isinstance(dist,Requirement): dist = get_provider(dist)
      File "/home/pyc6eh4uk/Programms/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 197, in get_provider
        return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
      File "/home/pyc6eh4uk/Programms/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
        needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
      File "/home/pyc6eh4uk/Programms/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: google-cloud-bigquery
```

So I think that problem in confilcts between google-cloud-sdk that located in my home directory and bigquery package in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud
How avoid this conflict or may be how setup enviroment that work google sdk and bigqery?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a quick test and I can’t reproduce this behavior. To isolate the issue what you can do is use a virtualenv just by doing the following:

-`$ virtualenv test`

-`$ pip freeze` (make sure there’s nothing installed)

-`$ source test/bin/activate`

-`$ pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`

Once installed you can follow the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) you are using so far and execute the script inside de virtualenv.
After you are done you can leave the virtualenv by running `$ deactivate`

Comment: It works in virtualenv. Why it does not work in ordinary enviroment. Let me try explain more in detail. I have PyCharm, in this IDE define google SDK in settings, so I can test how work my server localy. And also I installed bigquery(bq), for doing some jobs on server, in virtualenv  bq works, but in usual env does not work. Also, before install google SDK bigquery works.

Comment: Now I run script in command line and it works. But in PyCharm I have error what i subscribed.

Comment: Then this must be an issue with your local environment and PyCharm.